# Adding a custom view to the mapview that does not move with the map view

Tags: android, google-maps, android-custom-view, android-mapview

I want to add a view on top of mapview that does not move when I move the map view. The mapview can be zoomed in or zoomed out but the view should be stationary at the center of the map view. Please guide me how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: I need to do it programmatically and not through xml.

Comment: post some of your code

Answer (score 2):

This should be your xml code

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your Activity do this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
relativeLayout.addView(yourView, layoutParams);
```